# Multiple Kinects - 2nd openni_node never publishes anything

Tags: kinect, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to run multiple Kinects on one computer (for now just two Kinects).  I created a modified launch files to identify each kinect by its serial number, and launch it.  I'm using remap in the launch file to remap the /camera/* topics to /cameraXXXX where XXXX are the last 4 digits of the serial number.  I also have a launch file to launch a bunch of static transform broadcasters.

Here are my launch files.  I originally had the two camera nodes in the same launch file, but I separated them to help with troubleshooting.

The problem I'm having is this:  I can launch either camera node and everything works fine.  When I try to run both camera nodes at the same time, only the first one to launch publishes any point clouds (as determined by trying to view the point clouds in rviz, and using the rostopic hz command).  The other one never publishes any messages.

Any thoughts?  Does anyone have some example launch files that are known to work with multiple kinects?

Here are my launch files:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="launch_prefix" value=""/>  
  <node pkg="openni_camera" type="openni_node" name="openni_node113A" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
    <param name="device_id" value="A00364A14324113A"/> <!-- this line uses device with given serial number -->
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find openni_camera)/info/openni_params.yaml" />
    <param name="rgb_frame_id" value="/openni_rgb_optical_frame113A" />
    <param name="depth_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_optical_frame113A" />
    <param name="use_indices" value="false" />
    <param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
    <param name="image_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="debayering" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_time_offset" value="0" />
    <param name="image_time_offset" value="0" />
    <remap from="/camera" to="/camera113A"/>
  </node>
</launch>



<launch>
  <arg name="launch_prefix" value=""/>
  <node pkg="openni_camera" type="openni_node" name="openni_node045B" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
    <param name="device_id" value="B00362709389045B"/> <!-- this line uses device with given serial number -->
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find openni_camera)/info/openni_params.yaml" />
    <param name="rgb_frame_id" value="/openni_rgb_optical_frame045B" />
    <param name="depth_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_optical_frame045B" />
    <param name="use_indices" value="false" />
    <param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
    <param name="image_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="debayering" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_time_offset" value="0" />
    <param name="image_time_offset" value="0" />
    <remap from="/camera" to="/camera045B"/>
  </node>
</launch>



<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link_113A" args="0 -0.02 0 0 0 0  /openni_camera113A /openni_depth_frame113A 100" />  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link1_113A" args="0 -0.04 0 0 0 0  /openni_camera113A /openni_rgb_frame113A 100" />  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link2_113A" args="0 0 0 -1.57 0 -1.57 /openni_depth_frame113A /openni_depth_optical_frame113A  100" />  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link3_113A" args="0 0 0 -1.57 0 -1.57 /openni_rgb_frame113A /openni_rgb_optical_frame113A 100" />  

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link_045B" args="0 -0.02 0 0 0 0  /openni_camera045B /openni_depth_frame045B 100" />  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link1_045B" args="0 -0.04 0 0 0 0  /openni_camera045B /openni_rgb_frame045B 100" />  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link2_045B" args="0 0 0 -1.57 0 -1.57 /openni_depth_frame045B /openni_depth_optical_frame045B  100" />  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link3_045B" args="0 0 0 -1.57 0 -1.57 /openni_rgb_frame045B /openni_rgb_optical_frame045B 100" />  

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_113A_045B" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /openni_camera113A /openni_camera045B 100" />  
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10888/multiple-kinects---2nd-openni_node-never-publishes-anything/) by [bsatzinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/822/bsatzinger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/973/connecting-two-kinects-with-openni_camera-will

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0